# AngularJS OrderBy ASC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have a ng-repeat:

```
<label ng-repeat="atp in Keywords | unique:'atp'">
   {{atp}}
</label>
```

In `atp`, I got:

```
client
animal
zoo
boat
```

I expect in **output**:

```
animal
boat
client
zoo
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `unique` is not an angular built-in filter. If you did add it to your module, please show the code for it, because it could be the cause of the problem (as Jon's answer should actually work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<label ng-repeat="atp in Keywords | unique:'atp' | orderBy:atp">
   {{atp}}
</label>
```